# A Star Unpredictable Errors

Tags: c++, algorithm, path-finding, a-star

My feeble attempt at an A* Algorithm is generating unpredictable errors.
My FindAdjacent() function is clearly a mess, and it actually doesn't work when I step through it. This is my first time trying a path finding algorithm, so this is all new to me.

When the application actually manages to find the goal nodes and path (or so I think), it can never set the path (called from within main by pressing enter). I do not know why it is unable to do this from looking at the SetPath() function.

Any help would be hugely appreciated, here's my code:

**NODE CLASS**

```
enum 
{
    NODE_TYPE_NONE  = 0,
    NODE_TYPE_NORMAL,
    NODE_TYPE_SOLID,
    NODE_TYPE_PATH,
    NODE_TYPE_GOAL
};

class Node
{
public:

    Node            ()          : mTypeID(0), mNodeCost(0), mX(0), mY(0), mParent(0){};

public:

    int     mTypeID;
    int     mNodeCost;
    int     mX;
    int     mY;

    Node*   mParent;
};
```

**PATH FINDING**

```
/**
 *  finds the path between star and goal
 */
void AStarImpl::FindPath()
{
    cout << "Finding Path." << endl;
    GetGoals();

    while (!mGoalFound)
        GetF();
}

 /**
 *  modifies linked list to find adjacent, walkable nodes
 */
void AStarImpl::FindAdjacent(Node* pNode)
{
    for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
            if (i != 0 && j != 0)
                if (Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX+i][pNode->mY+j].mTypeID != NODE_TYPE_SOLID)
                {
                    for (vector<Node*>::iterator iter = mClosedList.begin(); iter != mClosedList.end(); iter++)
                    {
                        if ((*iter)->mX != Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX + i][pNode->mY + j].mX && (*iter)->mY != Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX + i][pNode->mY + j].mY)
                        {
                            Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX+i][pNode->mY+j].mParent = pNode;
                            mOpenList.push_back(&Map::GetInstance()->mMap[pNode->mX+i][pNode->mY+j]);
                        }
                    }
                }
    }

    mClosedList.push_back(pNode);
}

/**
 *  colour the found path
 */
void AStarImpl::SetPath()
{
    vector<Node*>::iterator tParent;
    mGoalNode->mTypeID = NODE_TYPE_PATH;

    Node *tNode = mGoalNode;

    while (tNode->mParent)
    {
        tNode->mTypeID  = NODE_TYPE_PATH;
        tNode           = tNode->mParent;
    }

}

/**
 *  returns a random node
 */
Node* AStarImpl::GetRandomNode()
{
    int tX      = IO::GetInstance()->GetRand(0, MAP_WIDTH - 1);
    int tY      = IO::GetInstance()->GetRand(0, MAP_HEIGHT - 1);

    Node* tNode = &Map::GetInstance()->mMap[tX][tY];

    return tNode;
}

/**
 *  gets the starting and goal nodes, then checks te starting nodes adjacent nodes
 */
void AStarImpl::GetGoals()
{
    //  get the two nodes
    mStartNode  = GetRandomNode();
    mGoalNode   = GetRandomNode();

    mStartNode->mTypeID     = NODE_TYPE_GOAL;
    mGoalNode->mTypeID      = NODE_TYPE_GOAL;

    //  insert start node into the open list
    mOpenList.push_back(mStartNode);

    //  find the starting nodes adjacent ndoes
    FindAdjacent(*mOpenList.begin());

    //  remove starting node from open list
    mOpenList.erase(mOpenList.begin());
}

/**
 *  finds the best f
 */
void AStarImpl::GetF()
{
    int     tF          = 0;
    int     tBestF      = 1000;

    vector<Node*>::const_iterator tIter;
    vector<Node*>::const_iterator tBestNode;

    for (tIter = mOpenList.begin(); tIter != mOpenList.end(); ++tIter)
    {
        tF  =   GetH(*tIter);
        tF  +=  (*tIter)->mNodeCost;

        if (tF < tBestF)
        {
            tBestF = tF;
            tBestNode = tIter;
        }
    }

    if ((*tBestNode) != mGoalNode)
    {
        Node tNode  = **tBestNode;
        mOpenList.erase(tBestNode);
        FindAdjacent(&tNode);
    }
    else
    {
        mClosedList.push_back(mGoalNode);
        mGoalFound = true;
    }
}

/**
 *  returns the heuristic from the given node to goal
 */
int AStarImpl::GetH(Node *pNode)
{
    int H =     (int) fabs((float)pNode->mX - mGoalNode->mX);
        H +=    (int) fabs((float)pNode->mY - mGoalNode->mY);
        H *=    10;

    return H;
}
```

Comment: Way too much code. What about a [SSCCE](http://homepage1.nifty.com/algafield/sscce.html)?

Comment: Fair enough. I'll try to shorten it. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few suggestions:

### ADJACENCY TEST

The test in FindAdjacent will only find diagonal neighbours at the moment

```
 if (i != 0 && j != 0)
```

If you also want to find left/right/up/down neighbours you would want to use

```
 if (i != 0 || j != 0)
```

### ADJACENCY LOOP

I think your code looks suspicious in FindAdjacent at the line

```
for (vector<Node*>::iterator iter = mClosedList.begin(); iter != mClosedList.end(); iter++)
```

I don't really understand the intention here.  I would have expected mClosedList to start empty, so this loop will never execute, and so nothing will ever get added to mOpenList.

My expectation at this part of the algorithm would be for you to test for each neighbour whether it should be added to the open list.

### OPENLIST CHECK

If you look at the [A* algorithm on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) you will see that you are also missing the section starting

```
if neighbor not in openset or tentative_g_score < g_score[neighbor]
```

in which you should also check in FindAdjacent whether your new node is already in the OpenSet before adding it, and if it is then only add it if the score is better.

Comment: Thank you very mcuh for this help. I'll be implementing the fixes straight after this.